# db_schema.xml Error Auto Increment column do not have index. Column - "id", table - "unicode_file_store", unicode_file_customer_group

Tags: magento2, db-schema

I have created db_schema.xml
When I run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command, I get this error

Auto Increment column do not have index. Column - "id", table - "unicode_file_store"Auto Increment column do not have index. Column - "id", table - "unicode_file_customer_group"

can anyone help me why i am getting this error

Thanks in advance

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DB/TestSchema/etc/db_schema.xsd">
    <table name="unicode_file" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Unicode File Table">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="Id"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="product_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Product Id"/>
        <column xsi:type="text" name="file_path" nullable="false" comment="File Url"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="file_name" length="255" nullable="false" comment="File Name"/>
        <column xsi:type="text" name="file_url" nullable="false" comment="File Link"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="file_size" padding="10" nullable="false" default="0" comment="File Size"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="file_type" length="255" nullable="false" default="" comment="File Type"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="id"/>
        </constraint>
        <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="PRODUCT_ID_FOREIGN" table="unicode_file"
                    column="product_id" referenceTable="catalog_product_entity" referenceColumn="entity_id"
                    onDelete="CASCADE"/>
    </table>

    <table name="unicode_file_store" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Unicode File Store Table">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true" primary="true" comment="Id"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="file_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="File Id"/>
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="store_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" default="0" comment="Store Id"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="label" length="255" default="null" nullable="false" comment="Label"/>
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="is_visible" nullable="false" default="0" comment="Is Visible"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="position" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Position"/>
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="show_for_ordered" nullable="false" default="0" comment="Show only if a Product has been Ordered"/>
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="customer_group_is_default" nullable="false" default="1" comment="Customer Group is from store_id=0"/>
        
        <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="FILE_ID_FOREIGN" table="unicode_file_store" 
                    column="file_id" referenceTable="unicode_file" referenceColumn="id"
                    onDelete="CASCADE"/>
    </table>

    <table name="unicode_file_customer_group" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Unicode File Customer Group Table">
       <column xsi:type="int" name="id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true" primary="true" comment="Id"/>
       <column xsi:type="int" name="file_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="File Id"/>
       <column xsi:type="smallint" name="store_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" default="0" comment="Store ID"/>
       <column xsi:type="smallint" name="customer_group_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" primary="true" comment="Customer Group Id"/>

       <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="FILE_ID_FOREIGN" table="unicode_file_customer_group" 
                    column="file_id" referenceTable="unicode_file" referenceColumn="id"
                    onDelete="CASCADE"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a primary key for your table.

```xml
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="id"/>
        </constraint>
```

Add the above code before the table closing tag for both tables.

Update:

Here's the full db_schema:

```xml
    <table name="unicode_file" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Unicode File Table">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="Id"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="product_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Product Id"/>
        <column xsi:type="text" name="file_path" nullable="false" comment="File Url"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="file_name" length="255" nullable="false" comment="File Name"/>
        <column xsi:type="text" name="file_url" nullable="false" comment="File Link"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="file_size" padding="10" nullable="false" default="0" comment="File Size"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="file_type" length="255" nullable="false" default="" comment="File Type"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="id"/>
        </constraint>
        <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="PRODUCT_ID_FOREIGN" table="unicode_file"
                    column="product_id" referenceTable="catalog_product_entity" referenceColumn="entity_id"
                    onDelete="CASCADE"/>
    </table>

    <table name="unicode_file_store" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Unicode File Store Table">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="Id"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="file_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="File Id"/>
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="store_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" default="0" comment="Store Id"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="label" length="255" default="null" nullable="false" comment="Label"/>
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="is_visible" nullable="false" default="0" comment="Is Visible"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="position" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Position"/>
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="show_for_ordered" nullable="false" default="0" comment="Show only if a Product has been Ordered"/>
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="customer_group_is_default" nullable="false" default="1" comment="Customer Group is from store_id=0"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="id"/>
        </constraint>
        <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="FILE_ID_FOREIGN" table="unicode_file_store"
                    column="file_id" referenceTable="unicode_file" referenceColumn="id"
                    onDelete="CASCADE"/>
    </table>

    <table name="unicode_file_customer_group" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Unicode File Customer Group Table">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="Id"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="file_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="File Id"/>
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="store_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" default="0" comment="Store ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="customer_group_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Customer Group Id"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="id"/>
        </constraint>
        <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="FILE_ID_FOREIGN" table="unicode_file_customer_group"
                    column="file_id" referenceTable="unicode_file" referenceColumn="id"
                    onDelete="CASCADE"/>
    </table>
```

Comment: i also defined primary key but still its giving me error when i run upgrade cmd

Comment: I tested your db_schema, and there was another problem. You can not define `primary=true` at least in Magento 2.4.6, it says `Element 'column', attribute 'primary': The attribute 'primary' is not allowed.`
I Updated my answer with the correct schema.

Comment: In `unicode_file_customer_group` table, do you want to have id and customer_group_id as the primary keys of the table?